# What is the intended purpose of @JobScope in Spring Batch? What's the intended way to share in-memory data between steps?

Tags: spring-batch

I'm using it today to cache objects between steps so that I don't have to build the entire job in a single step. At first, since my Steps were not annotated with any scope (though it's hard to make sense of them not implicitly being `@JobScope`) I ran into some gnarly unit testing issues claiming:

**Scope 'job' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for job scope**

I read (on the since abandoned Gitter thread (which was very informative)) that this may not be the right use case for @JobScope. Indeed I'm concerned now that the job scope is per thread somehow.

This leads me to the question of what is the purpose of `@JobScope`, if I really am misusing it?  And if I'm misusing it what is the right way to share data between Steps in the same job without writing to a database table/temporary file only to turn around and read it at the start of the next step?
As a side note: (and Spring Batch is no different than other frameworks in this regard) these questions stem from the available examples being too simplistic to have much bearing on real-world use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JobScope` in 90%+ of cases is a code smell.  It's why we avoided adding it for so many years.  It was really only added to Spring Batch because the feature was required for the JSR-352 implementation.

The "right" way to share data between steps is via a proper data store of some kind (db of some kind, NoSQL store, files, etc).  If your job goes down, you'd want that data to be available on a restart, which sharing those values in memory via a `JobScope` defined cache would not enable.  If you have large amounts of data, you'd want to persist that somewhere to be economical with your memory usage.  Also, as you've noted, the `JobScope` (just like the `StepScope`) is not available to all threads (since we don't manage all the threads in a job, there's no practical way to make that happen) so it limits its usefulness.

In the end, I have yet to find a use case where I've said that the `JobScope` is the right way to handle a given use case, this one included.

Comment: This is interesting as there is also something called a ListItemWriter which combined with @JobScope is an indication that sharing data (in-memory)  between steps is a thing.  The problem with writing to the database each time is we would have half-complete records in the database in our use case which doesn't seem right either.  I suppose we could try persisting to files between steps and that may* make it more resilient but that will take some thought.

Comment: Follow up post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60644783/what-is-the-best-way-to-flatten-a-list-of-lists-in-spring-batch